# CentOS 7.6 - Initrd.img not loading updated driver

Tags: centos, drivers, intel, initrd

I have been trying to load an updated initrd.img file with updated drivers on booting the Centos 7.6 ISO, however it seems to still load the old driver even though I have replaced the driver.

### Steps taken:

#### Extracted initrd image from ISO:

1. Mounted CentOS 7.6 ISO
2. Copied the initrd.img from isolinux/initrd.img to temporary folder (/tmp/image)
3. Created a new folder at /tmp/image/initrd
4. Extracted the initrd.img the folder by running

```bsh
xz -dc < ../initrd.img | cpio -idmv
```

#### Created the e1000e.ko.kz driver file

1. Download the latest e1000e NIC driver from the Intel website: 
   [e1000e download link](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCIe-Intel-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Connections-Under-Linux-)
2. Extracted the tar file

   ```bsh
   tar xvf e1000e-3.6.0.tar.gz
   ```
3. Make the source code, ensuring that gcc and kernel-devel libraries are installed

   ```bsh
   cd e1000e-3.6.0/src
   make install
   ```

   Note: this driver was compiled on a linux environment created by the CentOS 7.6 ISO.
4. Copy the created e1000e.ko file to the temporary folder (/tmp/image)
5. Compress it to .kz format

   ```bsh
   xz -k e1000e.ko
   ```

   #### Replace old driver and repack initrd.img image
6. Copy the compressed driver file to replace the existing driver

   ```bsh
   cp e1000e.ko.kz /tmp/image/initrd/files/lib/modules/3.10.0.957.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e
   ```
7. Repack the initrd.img

   ```bsh
   cd /tmp/image/initrd
   find . 2>/dev/null | cpio -c -o | xz -9 --check=crc32 > ../initrd.img
   ```
8. Copy the generated initrd.img back into the ISO at isolinux/initrd.img and images/pxe/initrd.img

### Expected Results

After updating the driver in the initrd.img and copying it into the ISO, I expect the new driver (e1000e version 3.6.0) to be loaded in after the ISO install boot process is complete.

### Actual Results

I am able to boot from the ISO and install Centos 7 from it, however after installing Centos, running the following command:

```bsh
modinfo e1000e
```

Gives the old version of the driver that was on the initrd.img initially (e1000e version 3.2.6) rather than version 3.6.0 which I loaded onto the initrd.img image.

I am not too sure what I am doing wrong, whether I am creating the driver incorrectly, loading the driver incorrectly, creating the initrd.img incorrectly or anything else.

Any help would be appreciated as I have been trying to get this working for the past few days. This is my first post, so let me know if I am doing anything wrong or if any additional information is required debug this issue.

Cheers

Comment: You probably also need to update the files/usr/lib/modules/3.10.0.957.el7.x86_64/modules.dep with the new module name and path (usually handled by depmod).  I think you'd do something like `depmod -b /tmp/image/initrd/usr 3.10.0.957.el7.x86_64` but please check if I'm wrong.

Comment: I didn't include a brand new driver, the e1000e driver module already existed in the initrd.img that I pulled from the ISO. I just updated the existing driver with a newer version, i.e. the module name and path didn't change for the new driver.

Comment: I was trying to follow your same approach, but it looks like the e100e driver is not enough when dealing with a new network card that was not supported before. kmod-e1000e-3.8.4-2.el7_8.elrepo.x86_64.rpm does support more, but adding the driver to the initrd is not enough. Any idea?

Comment: Did you do anything with the pci.updates?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured this out. The drivers are also in the LiveOS/squashfs.img rootfs.img. So the initrd modules get overlayed with rootfs.img. This is during the installation process but once the installed system boots the driver comes from an installed RPM (probably the kernel in this case) so initrd has nothing to do with it anymore. You would need to update that RPM or add a separate RPM with the updated driver for it to work on the installed system.